# WatchOS Background URLSession handle(_:) not called when app is not closed (lowered wrist)

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watch, watchos, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm trying to create a Watch-App where I download data (around 30 MB).

Therefore I create a URLSession with a background configuration like so:

```swift
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "<some-id>")
self.session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: .main)
```

and then start the download:

```swift
let request = URLRequest(url: "<some-url>", method: .GET)
self.task = session.downloadTask(with: request)
self.task.resume()
```

Since the user is not gonna stare at the watch for 5 minutes, I want to notify him with some haptic feedback when the download finished.
Therefore I wanted to use the `handle(_:)` function of the ExtensionDelegate. According to the documentation, this should be called with a `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask` when the download finished:

> The system creates a background URLSession task when any of the following events occur:
>   Authentication is required to complete a background transfer.
>   All background transfers associated with a session identifier have completed (either successfully or unsuccessfully). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkurlsessionrefreshbackgroundtask

This `handle(_:)` method is only called if I close my app though (pressing the crown), not when i lower my wrist to lock the screen.

I also noticed, that if I look at the watch again, the callbacks for `urlSession(.. didWriteData ..)` are not working anymore.

Am I missing something or is this even expected behaviour? I'm testing on a real Apple-Watch Series 4 with WatchOS 5 installed.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm never receiving a `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask`. The `ExtensionDelegate.handle()` method is never even called.